# Is there a workaround for the Piggy Bank crash on consoles?

Tags: terraria-console

There is currently a glitch in the console versions of Terraria where if you put items in a piggy bank then save and exit, they will turn into random items. The more common items are stacks of 5-900 random iron tools.

However, if you add a certain amount at one time, the game will crash every time you launch it. Downloading it again doesn't help, and I don't want to restart. Is there any way to fix my game?

Comment: don't use the piggy bank?

Comment: @Rapitor Hah, was about to write the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **According to the *"piggy bank bug"* excerpt on the [Terraria Wikia](http://terraria.wikia.com) page of [Known Bugs](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Known_Bugs_%28Console%29#Fixed_Bugs),**
>
> *Sometimes items in your inventory will be removed, but only small portions of them. This is a sign of a save that is soon to be corrupted*

**It appears the bug corrupts the ID number of the item in the piggy bank**. I could speculate that the *item ID* and *stack count* are being calculated together, as you could exploit the bug to deliberately create glitched items. It appears **the "random item" generated is actually determined by the item ID and stack count of the original item**. For example, ***a stack of 3 dirt would generate stone***.

The problem with this is that **it can corrupt your save**.

Once your save is corrupted, it can be difficult to fix. **The standard fix for corruption is "wipe and restart"**. Is the game crashing on launch, or **does it only crash when you load the world?** If just the world is causing the crash, at least **you only have to bomb the world**, and not your character.

You will notice that **the bug is now listed as a fixed bug**, so **updating your game over Xbox live should guarantee this does not happen again**. Better yet, you might find that updating the game fixes your problem from the get go.

Comment: As previously stated, the Xbox live update has resolved all of my problems (at the expense of my worlds and characters).

Answer (score 1):

Check your hard-drive or storage device for your terraria saves, move them or preferably delete them, then uninstall, then reinstall.

Answer (score -2):

use safe instead, its the same but more expensive.

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade! While you gave a good response, you might want to take a little more time and effort with your answers, to reduce the chance of being down voted.

Take the time to write a few sentences. Provide links. For this instance, you could have linked to the terraria wikia page on the item. I, myself, did a quick google check to add the link on your behalf, and the first page that came up detailed that **the bug effecting OPs game effects safes just the same**.